# What is the bitrate of my audio file based on ffmpeg output?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Is it the 40kb/s under `Format`, or is it the 16kb/s under `Stream`? What is the relationship between the Format and the Stream?
The below output is for a file generated using Core Audio on an iphone, with an Audio Unit. The output format was specified by an `AudioStreamBasicDescription` descriptor

**Updated:**
Output from `ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams 123_1429602551009.051025.m4a` :

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/8000
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=8000
channels=1
channel_layout=mono
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/8000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=43008
duration=5.376000
bit_rate=16501
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=42
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:creation_time=1970-04-16 22:36:01
TAG:language=eng
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=123_1429602551009.051025.m4a
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=5.376000
size=27473
bit_rate=40882
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=M4A
TAG:minor_version=0
TAG:compatible_brands=M4A mp42isom
TAG:creation_time=1970-04-16 22:36:01
TAG:iTunSMPB= 00000000 00000840 00000361 0000000000009C5F 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard the size of the file is 27473 bytes, the duration is 5.38 seconds

Comment: The "format" duration of 40 kb/s is correct (27473 / 5.38 = 40 kb/s for whole file), but that does not mean that the audio stream shares the same bitrate. Please update your question with the output from this command: `ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams input.m4a`. Then highlight the text and press `command` + `k`, or use the code button, to properly format it. You can then remove the previous command and output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks, I've updated the format and added the output from the new command.

Comment: Of course I meant "format bitrate" instead of "format duration" in my previous comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format bitrate is the **overall bitrate**, in your case `40 kb/s`. `16kb` is the bitrate of the AAC audio stream found in your m4a container.

Comment: Apologies if I'm being dense, but could you explain how overall bitrate differs from the bitrate of the stream? I'm not well versed in the intricacies of media encoding.

Comment: The stream bitrate is the rate of just the inner stream data. The format bitrate is the rate of the stream data + the format data, therefore it's bigger.

Comment: It's like having a smaller box in a bigger one. If you were to extract the raw AAC (stream) from the m4a (container) it would have `16 kb/s`.